# Render a splash screen in Vue while fetching data of another view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I need to show a splash screen while data is loaded in the final view.

I have this in router:

```
 {
    path: "/home",
    name: "Home",
    component: () =>
      import(
        /* webpackPrefetch: true */ /* webpackChunkName: "general" */ "@/views/Home"
      ),
    meta: {
      layout: "MainLayout",
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      store.dispatch("modGeneral/actGetNews").then(() => {
        next();
      });
    },
  },
```

I need to show another route while this is working: `store.dispatch("modGeneral/actGetNews")`, maybe put any timeout to render it but I can't figure it out yet how to do that.

Comment: Why not pushing a new route when the call is done?

Comment: Because there is a icon where user clicks and go back to the last route. So, I have now a route called Articles (where is the splash) and it takes me to Articles Home. But if I click go back in Articles Home, it will take me to the Splash and no the real route I was before.

Comment: You can always `$router.replace`.